# Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I create a new react-native project and write a redux demo.IOS Simulator show the error 'Expected the reducer to be a function'.I tried to solve the problem from the preview answers,but it doesn't work

index.ios.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {reducers} from './src/reducer';
import {App} from './src/App';

const store = createStore(reducers)

export default class rnredux extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Provider store ={store}>
          <App/>
        </Provider>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rnredux', () => rnredux);
```

App.js

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import MyComponent from './myComponent';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {text: state.text, name: state.name}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onChange: (e) => dispatch({type: 'change', payload: e.target.value})
    }
}

const App = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);

export default App;
```

myComponent.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text,TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class myComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        <View>
            <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
            <TextInput defaultValue = {this.props.name} onChangeText = {this.props.onChange}></TextInput>
        </View>
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const reducerAction = (state = {
  text: '你好，访问者',
  name: '访问者'
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'change':
      return {
        name: action.payload,
        text: '你好，' + action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
    reducerAction
})

export default reducers;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change

```
import {reducers} from './src/reducer';
import {App} from './src/App';
```

to

```
import reducers from './src/reducer';
import App from './src/App';
```

When you import the module's default, dont't use brace`{}`.

Comment: can you please explain what is the difference between
{reducers} and reducers. it worked for me though, but still i want to know.

Comment: @Vijender Kumar The `reducers` is used to import the function or variable that use the keyword `default` the  module exports,the `{reducers}` is used to import the other function. The default function just like `module.exports` in nodejs,other function without `default` like `exports`.