# When using React Native Debugger, "Expected the reducer to be a function" happens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was following a React Native tutorial.
I was trying to connect it to React Native Debugger app.

But then I got "Expected the reducer to be a function" error.
It says here that it is caused by `{}` around the module I'm importing.,
[Expected the reducer to be a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827134/expected-the-reducer-to-be-a-function)

So I did fix it by removing `{}`
Basically, it works when `import composeWithDevTools` and it errors when `import {composeWithDevTools}` when connected to React Native Debugger.

**But I cannot understand why!**

1. The tutorial I'm following works totally fine with `import {composeWithDevTools}` when connected to React Native Debugger.
2. It works **fine** when NOT connected to React Native Debugger.

Is this an error on React Native Debugger? Why does this happen?

Edit: I re-started metro many times. It always produces the same result.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './reducers/user';
import composeWithDevTools from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error came from a different place than what the debugger pointed to.

Problem is here. `const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools);`

This should be

`const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());`

with `()` added at the last argument.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem with the course I'm following :)

Answer (score 0):

It's good to follow [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm)

You need the curly bracket. If it's behaviour is weird, or you have just installed a new package, maybe it's a good habit to **restart the metro**.

[image: From documentation]

Comment: I restarted the metro many times. It does not solve the problem unfortunately.